# Problem with Ipython notebook and Pyzmq, (plus Jupyter)

Tags: python, pip, ipython

I had trouble installing Ipython, but fortunately I tried version 3.2.1 and everything went ok and I can run Ipython, but I still can't run Ipython notebook.

```
$ ipython

Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.


$ ipython notebook
...
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

I tried to install pyzmq and I got the following error:

```
$ sudo pip install -U pyzmq
...
Warning: Failed to build or run libzmq detection test.



If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:



    * You have a C compiler installed

    * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)

    * A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including headers)

    * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>

    * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,

      try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`



      or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`
       ...
          compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I copied only the error because there are hundreds of lines executed by the shell.

Information :
Python Version 2.7.9
I have Anaconda, (don't know if it changes anything)
Ubuntu 15.04 
I have Canopy (Python IDE) installed (don't know if it changes anything)

EDIT : I was trying some other stuff, and then I decided to try to install jupyter. I noticed that even after a clean installation (with pip) I was unable to run jupyter.

```
$ jupyter notebook
jupyter : command not found.
```

but now I can run :

```
~$ ipython notebook
[I 00:33:30.336 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 00:33:30.386 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/renanpc
[I 00:33:30.386 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 00:33:30.386 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 00:33:30.386 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

(process:11118): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
^C[I 00:37:24.548 NotebookApp] interrupted
Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/renanpc
0 active kernels 
The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
```

and the Notebook runs just fine. I am very very confused with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem yet
You should try the following thing:
which ipython 
- in my case I got - "/opt/local/bin/ipython"
Then
ls -l /opt/local/bin/ipython 
this'll show you where the link leads
"lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    71B 11 фев 17:49 /opt/local/bin/ipython@ -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython"
Now 
ls /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ 
- if you see jupyter in output - simply do the following:
ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/jupyter /opt/local/bin/